# Change image src every second

Tags: javascript

I have 4 images and I want to make a scroller with the following logic. Each element must:

1. popup
2. become bigger
3. become smaller (return to previous state)
4. disappear

I've decided to make 4 different animations for this and assign them to 4 different classes. 
What I need is to make it endless, so I've come up with idea to change image src every second. I wrote the code but it doesn't work. Nothing happens and no errors also.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    for (var n = 1; n <= 4; n++) {
      if (n == 4) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('animation-slide-4')[0].alt = 'im1';
      } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('animation-slide-' + n.toString())[0].alt = 'im' + (n + 1).toString();
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}, false);
```

```css
@keyframes animation-1 {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}

@keyframes animation-2 {
  from {
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 70px;
    width: 400px;
  }
}

@keyframes animation-3 {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 70px;
    width: 400px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.3;
    top: 110px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@keyframes animation-4 {
  from {
    opacity: 0.3;
    top: 110px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 140px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="slide slide-img animation-slide-1" src="img/1.png" alt="im1"><br>
<img class="slide slide-img animation-slide-2" src="img/2.png" alt="im2"><br>
<img class="slide slide-img animation-slide-3" src="img/4.png" alt="im3"><br>
<img class="slide slide-img animation-slide-4" src="img/3.png" alt="im4"><br>
```

Comment: 1. get rid of `eval(n + 1)` use just `(n+1)` there's no need to use eval here. 
2. you probably will need `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout`
3. it would be great if you give us a snippet or jsFiddle to debug

Comment: 4. when using `getElementsByClassName` you get a collection of elements, even if just one element is selected, so you need to use `[0]` after the selection, or select the elements by `id`, giving a unique id to each `img`

Comment: @CalvinNunes thank you, it started working but not the way I expected. I've added a code snippet but made it change 'alt' instead of src. It runs only once too.

Comment: I think the reason its only happening once is because the event you're listening for is 'DOMContentLoaded' which only happens when the page loads. If you want these changes to happen consecutively, I would use a setTimeout and call each change individually after a certain time period

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function myFunc(n) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('animation-slide-' + n.toString())[0].src = 'img/' + (n + 1).toString() + '.png';
}

  function myFunc1() {
             document.getElementsByClassName('animation-slide-4')[0].src = 'img/1.png';
}
setInterval(function() {
    for (var n = 1; n <= 4; n++) {
      if (n == 4) {
      var m =700;
 setInterval(myFunc1(),m);
 m=m+700;
      } else {
    
        
      setInterval(myFunc(n),m);
       m=m+700;
               
      }
    }
  },1000);
}, false);
```

```css
@keyframes animation-1 {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}

@keyframes animation-2 {
  from {
    top: 30px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 70px;
    width: 400px;
  }
}

@keyframes animation-3 {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 70px;
    width: 400px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.3;
    top: 110px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@keyframes animation-4 {
  from {
    opacity: 0.3;
    top: 110px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 140px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="slide slide-img animation-slide-1" src="img/1.png" alt="im1"><br>
<img class="slide slide-img animation-slide-2" src="img/2.png" alt="im2"><br>
<img class="slide slide-img animation-slide-3" src="img/4.png" alt="im3"><br>
<img class="slide slide-img animation-slide-4" src="img/3.png" alt="im4"><br>
```

Comment: still runs only once

Comment: @Desiigner try to change the browser.

Comment: I got it wrong. It runs but it changes DOM contents only once.